# help with writing a batch job on ContentDocumentLink?

Tags: apex, trigger, batch

However, I don't have any experience with writing batch classes and not sure what the syntax is, as i'm used to triggers. I was wondering if anyone could supply some good documentation, examples, trailheads, etc. for me to check out in order to get my head wrapped around how to accomplish this ask?

Thanks!

Comment: A web search turns up many excellent beginner resources, starting with Batch Apex Trailhead.  What you have tried?

Comment: @DavidCheng will check this trailhead out! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Batchable class implements an the Database.Batchable Interface.  I recommned following the example called "Using Database.QueryLocator to Define Scope" on this page: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm

The actual logic in your execute is going to be very similar to a Trigger Handler's logic.  Some things to keep in mind:

1. Batch Size defaults to 200, but can be set when you invoke the batchable
2. When testing Batchables, you must ensure that only one batch is processed, you can do so by either limiting the data in the text context OR ensuring that your query has a limit clause lower than your batch size (default 200).

Comment: thank you i will look into this!